# Horizontal Waterfall graph in data studio h

Tags: graph, looker-studio, waterfall

Does anybody knows how to "transpose" a waterfall graph in data studio?
By default, this graph shows vertical bars, but I want them to be horizontal, I think this should be easy.
[image: Initially this is how it looks]

I just want to turn it around, so that the bars are horizontal

Additionally, can I give a different color to each bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this and i used HighchartsReact. => Result
[image]

```html
   <HighchartsReact
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={{
      chart: {
        type: 'waterfall',
        inverted: true,
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: '',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:,.3f}</b>',
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      series: [{
        upColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        data: dataWaterfall,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function() {
            return Number(this.y).toFixed(3);
          },
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        },
        pointPadding: 0,
      }],
    }}
  />
```